# Auto-Create polygons from Geo-referenced PDF

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, georeferencing, polygon-creation

Is it possible to automatically create polygons/features from a georeferenced PDF?

I'd like to geo-reference an expanded view of the below linked pdf, and then have each of the tracts created automatically in a separate shapefile. I know it would probably be too much to ask for to have the Tract numbers also added as attributes, so I'd need to add those later.

[Map Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6cgjo8oc1tshqo1/Map%203%20%28TitleTract%20ID%27s%29.pdf?dl=0)

I'm using ArcMap Desktop 10.1 Advanced License. I attempted to convert to polyline like crid suggested, and after a couple of hours, the process appeared to complete and then arcmap crashed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try converting the raster to a polyline (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-polyline.htm) and, subsequently, converting the lines to polygons (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-polygon.htm). The feature to polygon tool requires an advanced license; if you don't have an advanced license I'll update my answer to show you how to create a polygon geometry from a line geometry. EDIT: to do that you'd have to have the line segments for each closed area as one line, which might not be the case for the raster to line.

You may have an issue with the polylines not creating a fully closed area; you can use extend lines (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/extend-line.htm) and/or snapping to fix that issue.